# 'web browser' program works in Windows but not Linux

Tags: c, network-programming, browser

I am not going to post my code, it is for a school project and I don't want to risk having my code copied. That being said I don't expect an concrete answer but any thoughts would be appreciated.

Anyway, my assignment was as follows: I am suppose to simulate a web browser in the terminal. The user provides an IP address, file path and port number. I then have to create the get request send it to the server and parse the file's content length from the response. Finally I am to use the content length to count the bytes as I read in the file so I know when the read is complete. All of this data is to be written to an html file.

The weird part is I started working on this on my home machine (Linux) and was able to parse the content length and queue to the beginning of the html file and start reading. After after each read I subtract the number of bytes I read from the content length and when I zero out I haven't read the entire file. However, if I run this on one of the school machines (Windows using cygwin) it reads the entire file.

I've debugged using print statments and confirmed that I am parsing the content length correctly and the countdown is working also. It has me scratching my head. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Check line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you determine that you haven't read the entire file? Are you relying on EOF? If so are you aware of HTTP/1.1 connection persistence?

Comment: No EOF would be the easy way but we are not allowed to use it. We have to parse the file length from the "Content-Length" header. It is suppose to tell the file length in bytes. Then you have to queue up to the beginning of the html file. Then you basicly keep track of the number of bytes read.

Comment: Just to remove extra variables from the problem, what is the server you're using for testing?

Comment: I can't check right now (my computer with my code and wireshark is at home) but I'm 99% sure it is Apache

Comment: Just making sure that it's not a homebrew server. When you say bytes read do you mean `int bytes_read = read(fd, buff, 256);` or `read(fd, buff, 256); int bytes_read = 256;`?

Comment: yeah the professor has us using a max buffer size of 80. However on the final read I may have to read less than 80 bytes. Say I have a 85 bytes to read. I read 80 bytes leaving me with five. Then on the final read I would read 5.

Comment: Yes but how do you increment your total_bytes_read variable? Do you do `total_bytes_read += read(fd, buff, 80);` The reason I ask is that the read function will read what's available and return the byte count unless the fd was opened with special flags.

Comment: Oh wow that could be my problem. I am just assuming that it reads the correct amount each time. I was just subtracting 80 each time but the final. I think you fixed my problem! You are awesome.

Comment: @Pinsickle: Don't forget to watch out for `read()` returning `-1`, indicating an error rather than a number of bytes read.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the stdio library that you are using on Windows does translations on any CR-LF combinations in the data. Check your compiler's manual for the open function and make sure that the mode is binary. This is a classical porting problem which requires different code to be compiled using ifdefs.

Check if your Windows compiler supports a constant like WIN32 which you can use like this

```
#if defined(WIN32)
   /* do this */
#else
   /* do that */
#endif
```